# Loop thru image "srcset" attribute and replace filetype suffix

Tags: jquery, srcset

I'm using feature detection to determine if a browser supports the `.webp` format & loading javascript for only those browsers. The reason I'm doing it client-side is that the PHP solution (using .htaccess) doesn't work, probably because my CDN is caching the JPEG, PNG or GIF versions.

This code works, except it throws an error (`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'match' of undefined`), and that error stops all other scripts in their tracks. Not pretty.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
  $('a[href$=".jpg"]').each(function (index, element) {
    element.href = element.href.replace(/\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$/i, '.webp');
  });
  $('img').each(function (index, element) {
    var elem = $(this);
    if (elem.attr('src').match(/\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$/i)); {
      element.src = element.src.replace(/\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$/i, '.webp');
    }
  });
  $('img').each(function (index, element) {
    var elem = $(this);
    if (elem.attr('srcset').match(/\.(gif|jpe?g|png)/ig)) {
      element.srcset = element.srcset.replace(/\.(gif|jpe?g|png)/ig, '.webp');
    }
  });
});
```

If I change `$('img').each(function (index, element) {` to `$('.element img').each(function (index, element) {`the error goes away, but the script no longer replaces the suffixes.

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 2):

There's a couple of `match` in there, but it's always a good idea to check if something really is what you think it is.

In this case `attr()` most likely returns `undefined` for one or more elements, so you have to check for that

```
$('img').each(function (index, element) {
    var elem   = $(this),
        scrset = elem.attr('srcset');

    if (srcset && srcset.match(/\.(gif|jpe?g|png)/ig)) {
        element.srcset = element.srcset.replace(/\.(gif|jpe?g|png)/ig, '.webp');
    }
});
```

Doing `if (srcset && srcset.match...` means the second check doesn't run if the first one fails, which it does when a falsy value like `null` or `undefined` is passed in.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, Adeneo. That put me on the right path. <del>Here's the final, working code:</del>

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
  if ($('html').hasClass('webp')) {
    $('a[href$=".jpg"]').each(function (index, element) {
      var path = $(this).attr('href');
      if (typeof path !== typeof undefined && path !== false) {
        element.href = element.href.replace(/\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$/i, '.webp');
      }
    });
    $('img').each(function (index, element) {
      var elem = $(this);
      var source = $(this).attr('src');
      if ((typeof source !== typeof undefined && source !== false) && elem.attr('src').match(/\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$/i)); {
        element.src = element.src.replace(/\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$/i, '.webp');
      }
      var sourceset = $(this).attr('srcset');
      if ((typeof sourceset !== typeof undefined && sourceset !== false) && elem.attr('srcset').match(/\.(gif|jpe?g|png)/ig)) {
        element.srcset = element.srcset.replace(/\.(gif|jpe?g|png)/ig, '.webp');
      }
    });
  }
});
```

EDIT: Turns out my `webp` paths end in `.jpg.webp` etc. So I had to rewrite the code to this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
  if ($('html').hasClass('webp')) {
    $('a[href$=".jpg"]').each(function (index, element) {
      var path = $(this).attr('href');
      if (typeof path !== typeof undefined && path !== false) {
        path = $(this).attr("href", path + ".webp");
      }
    });
    $('img').each(function (index, element) {
      var elem = $(this);
      var source = $(this).attr('src');
      if ((typeof source !== typeof undefined && source !== false) && source.match(/\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$/i)); {
        source = $(this).attr("src", source + ".webp");
      }
      var sourceset = $(this).attr('srcset');
      if ((typeof sourceset !== typeof undefined && sourceset !== false) && elem.attr('srcset').match(/\.jpg/ig)) {
        element.srcset = element.srcset.replace(/\.jpg/ig, '.jpg.webp');
        element.srcset = element.srcset.replace(/\.jpeg/ig, '.jpeg.webp');
        element.srcset = element.srcset.replace(/\.gif/ig, '.gif.webp');
        element.srcset = element.srcset.replace(/\.png/ig, '.png.webp');
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Any advice on refactoring for efficiency welcome.